# Hibernate recursive objects

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using `Java 8` with `Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE`, `JPA 2` and `Hibernate 5.2.1.Final` and `MySQL`.

```
+-----+     +-------------+    +----------+     +------------------------+
| Job |     |  Person_Job |    |  Person  |     |  Person_job_favourites |
+-----+     +-------------+    +----------+     +------------------------+
|  ID |     |    PER_ID   |    |    ID    |     |       PER_ID           |
|     |     |    JOB_ID   |    |          |     |       JOB_ID           |
+-----+     +-------------+    +----------+     +------------------------+
```

I have a `Job` object. `Job` Contains a `Person` object. The `Person` object has a list of `Favourite Jobs`.

**Job.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "person_job", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
private Person person;
```

**Person.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "person_job_favourites", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
private Set<Job> favouriteJobs;
```

As you can see, there is recursion, and the result set blows up.

**Question**

I am hoping not to have to totally redesign my schema, because I have done quite a bit of development around this. Is there a way to stop the recursion at a specific point? i.e. When I query for `Job` objects, return the `Person` objects and their `Job` favourites, but those `Job` favourites don't contain `Person` objects.

Comment: Shouldn't  favoriteJobs be a ManyToMany relation? Otherweise a Job can only be the favorite of a single Person which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will make that update. Thank you.

Comment: I purpose you to destruct your `Person_job_favourites` table and transform your `Person_Job` by adding an `Favourite` column in it ; because the couple `PER_ID` + `JOB_ID` is unique, so you can mark it as favourite or not.

Comment: By the way, the relation Job => Person and Person => Job are both ManyToMany.

Comment: Thanks, I will update the ManyToMany relationships.

Comment: So in the end you should create an JobPerson object in order to carry the relation between Jobs and Persons and the Favourite or not flag.

Comment: So I have a separate `JobPerson` entity (table & java class), instead of a join table (`PERSON_JOB`)?

Comment: Can you post your code of Person_job_favourites?

Comment: Person_job_favourites is just a join table, not a java entity, so there's no code except the reference to it above in the table join.  (I am currently doing an implementation without this join table though, by creating a FavouriteJobs entity, that's only called when needed).